# Having trouble making a loop that hides individual images one at a time (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I'm working on a game where I have 5 pieces (image files) set on each side of the board. As the game is running, I'm trying to get one of those individual pieces to disappear as the player/computer makes a selection. With the way I have it written (in JavaScript), when either the player or computer make their first square selection. All of the pieces on their side disappear.

JavaScript:

```js
let activePlayer= 'X';
let selectedSquares= []; //This array stores an array of moves. We use this to determine win conditions.

let xS = document.getElementsByClassName("Xs");
let oS = document.getElementsByClassName("Os");
let xMoves = 0;
let oMoves = 0;

function placeXOrO(squareNumber) { //This function is for placing an X or O in a square.
//The condition below ensures a square hasn't been selected already. The .some() method is used to check each element of selectedSquare array to see if it contains the square number clicked on.
if (!selectedSquares.some(element => element.includes(squareNumber))) {
    let select= document.getElementById(squareNumber); //This variable retrieves the html element id that was clicked.
    if (activePlayer === 'X') { //This condition checks who's turn it is.
        select.style.backgroundImage= 'url("images/nesX.png")'; //If activePlayer is equal to "X", the x.png is placed in HTML.
        xS[xMoves].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        xMoves++;
    } else { //Active player may only be "X" or "O" so,  if not "X" it must be "O".
        select.style.backgroundImage= 'url("images/nesO.png")'; //If activePlayer is equal to "O", the o.png is placed in HTML.
        oS[oMoves].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        oMoves++;
    }
    selectedSquares.push(squareNumber + activePlayer); //squareNumber and activePlayer are concatenated together and added to array.
    checkWinConditions(); //This calls a function to check for any win conditions.
    if (activePlayer === 'X') { //This condition is for changing the active player.
        activePlayer= 'O'; //If active player is "X" change it to "O".
    } else { //If active player is anything other than "X".
        activePlayer= 'X'; //Change the activePlayer to "X".
    }
    audio('./media/place1.mp3'); //This function plays placement sound.
    if(activePlayer === 'O') { //This condition checks to see if it is the computers turn.
        disableClick(); //This function disables clicking for computer choice.
        setTimeout(function (){ computersTurn(); }, 1000) //This function waits 1 second before computer places image and enables click.
    }
    return true; //Returning true is needed for our computersTurn() function to work.
}
function computersTurn() { //This function results in a random square being selected.
    let success= false; //This boolean is needed for our while loop.
    let pickASquare; //This variable stores a random number 0-8.
    while(!success) { //This condition allows our while loop to keep trying if a square is selected already.
        pickASquare= String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)); //A random number between 0 and 8 is selected.
        if (placeXOrO(pickASquare)) { //This line calls the function.
            placeXOrO(pickASquare); //This line changes our boolean and ends the loop.
            success= true;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="Xs">
    <img id="x1" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x1">
    <img id="x2" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x2">
    <img id="x3" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x3">
    <img id="x4" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x4">
    <img id="x5" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x5">
</div>
<div class="Os">
    <img id="o1" src="./images/nesO.png" alt="o1">
    <img id="o2" src="./images/nesO.png" alt="o2">
    <img id="o3" src="./images/nesO.png" alt="o3">
    <img id="o4" src="./images/nesO.png" alt="o4">
    <img id="o5" src="./images/nesO.png" alt="o5">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add some class to those images, like `class="Xs"` for X images, and `class="Os"` for O images. Then you can do code like this:

```js
let xS = document.getElementsByClassName("Xs");
let oS = document.getElementsByClassName("Os");
let xMoves = 0;
let oMoves = 0;

// ... 

function placeXOrO(squareNumber) {
  // ...
  if (activePlayer === 'X') { 
    xS[xMoves].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    xMoves++;
  } else {
    oS[oMoves].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    oMoves++;
  }
  // ...
}
```

This is much more compact and readable.

**Note:** if there are more possible moves, then there are images, then range check is needed before accessing the indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion MaBed. With what you said, the game does run. However on the first loop cycle it hides all the images. Do i need to create an array for the Xs/Os classes and try to go that route? Thank you. (Also, i've updated the code above to current).

Comment: @SoulSerrated So you are saying that calling `placeXOrO` function hides all the images? Or is it that the `placeXOrO` function called multiple times so it will hide them all? I also noticed that you call `placeXOrO` twice in each cycle of the `while`, is this intended?

Comment: When the placeXOrO function runs, the first loop cycle does work but instead of taking 1 chip from either side, it takes all 5.I think at this line: xS[xMoves].style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: Oh, I see now. You added the classes `Os` and `Xs` to parent `div`s. It should be on the `img`s elements like this:
`<img id="x1" class="Xs" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x1">`
`<img id="x2" class="Xs" src="./images/nesX.png" alt="x2">`
etc.